# How large is the key-value dataset of Tether?

Tags: tokens

If I understand things correctly, ERC20 tokens, like Tether, store the amount of Tether owned by each adres in the contract. With a very popular token like Tether, approximately how large is this dataset in kilobytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2022-05-18 14:35:00 UTC the [Tether USDT contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) has a total of 4,568,883 holders.

It will consume 4,568,883 x 32 bytes = 146,204,256 bytes = 139.43 Mbytes.

Comment: Are there smart contracts like this that are for some reason not "self contained", in the sense that the data of the contract is spread over multiple subcontracts?

Comment: @user2520938 I don't understand the reason for the question but Uniswap has separate contracts for each token pair, so the database is distributed between them.